# How long do other terminators live - I mean last - whatever?

Tags: the-terminator-series

In T2, John Connor asks the Uncle Bob version of the T-800 how long he'll last. The T-800 responds by saying that he will exist for 120 years with his existing power cell.

Is there anything within the Terminator canon which states how long the other terminators would live - er, last - before failing? Other versions of the T-800, the T-850, T-1000, and T-X are the terminators in view here.

Comment: This seems very broad and open to opinion-based speculation. You might want to narrow it down.

Comment: How is it open to speculation if the answer is based on canon?

Comment: Well, the latter two terminators you've mentioned are only found in a fairground ride.

Comment: Is not the T-Infinity in a Terminator comic book?

Comment: I suspect we won't get a proper answer to this until Genisys with the time-worn Terminator.

Comment: @T-1000 this question should be easy for you to answer; how long will you last?

Comment: @Moogle Wolfie's fine, honey, Wolfie's just fine. Where are you?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the Randall Frakes novelisation of T2: Judgement Day, the answer is that the T-1000 and T-X are likely to remain functional indefinitely. Presumably self-recharging is one of the benefits of being made of a prototype liquid-metal alloy:

> *"Although terminators had internal chronometers, the T-1000 did not. It was part of Skynet’s new design.  Knowledge  of  time  had  its  uses,  but  in  most  cases  of pursuit,  it  was  an  unnecessary  element.  **Time  did  not matter  when  the  thing  after  you  could  not  be  killed, could not be stopped, and would never tire"***